# Autowired dependency when passing data from Controller to Service layer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, autowired

I am making a Spring web app without any Hibernate/database connection. I merely want to pass data from the `Controller` layer to the `Service` that contains the "meat" of the application.

Whenever I try to add the lines:

```
@Autowired
private CalcArffService calcArffService;
```

into the controller, an exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app.service.CalcArffService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

when I try to access **all the pages**.

**How do I solve this?**

---

Here are the necessary files:

**`CalcController.java`**

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import app.domain.BreastCancer;
import app.service.CalcArffService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "calc")
public class CalcController {

  protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

  @ModelAttribute("breastCancer")
  public BreastCancer createModel() {
    return new BreastCancer();
  }

  @Autowired
  private CalcArffService calcArffService; // causes trouble tbh

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showCalcPage(ModelMap model) {
    /* stuff */
    return "calc";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String showResultsPage(
      @ModelAttribute("breastCancer") BreastCancer breastCancer,
      BindingResult result) {
    logger.info(breastCancer.toString());
    //calcArffService.evaluate(breastCancer);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
      return "calc";
    } else {
      return "redirect:calc/results";
    }
  }
}
```

**`CalcArffService.java`**

```
import app.domain.BreastCancer;

public interface CalcArffService {

  /**
   * 
   * @param breastCancer
   */
  public void evaluate(BreastCancer breastCancer);

}
```

**`CalcArffServiceImpl.java`**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Service("calcArffService")
public class CalcArffServiceImpl implements CalcArffService {

  protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

  @Autowired
  private CalcArffService calcArffService;

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void evaluate(BreastCancer breastCancer) {
    logger.info(breastCancer.toString());
  }

}
```

**`web.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
      id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>bosom</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**`spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="app.controller" />
      <context:component-scan base-package="app.service" />
      <context:component-scan base-package="app.service.impl" />

      <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
          value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      </bean>

      <!--Enables many annotations and searches for @Controller annotated methods 
        etc.. -->
      <context:annotation-config />

      <!--JSR-303 (Bean validation) support will be detected on classpath and 
        enabled automatically -->
      <mvc:annotation-driven />

      <!--This tag allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (all extensions 
        etc) -->
      <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

      <mvc:annotation-driven />
      <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
      <mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
      <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" />

    </beans>
```

**`Full stack trace`**

```
 SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app.service.CalcArffService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
      at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have duplicated `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`. The component-scan for `app.service` already includes `app.service.impl` it is the starting point and everything below it will be scanned. Finally your service is problematic as it introduces a cyclic dependency, the service is injected into itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup the component scanner to scan for beans in your service package.  In `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` add:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.service" />
```

In order for dependency injection to work, the component being injected and the component receiving the injection must both be beans.  Both the service and the bean must be discovered via component scanning.

Comment: Sir can you please replace the `base-package` in your answer with `app.service` (for personal protection)? Thank you.

Comment: You can specify multiple component-scan tags.

Comment: I added the `component-scan` for the controller and service but when I visited the page it showed an `HTTP 500` error with `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app.service.CalcArffService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: Did you also add `app.service`?

Comment: Yes, I added the proper package names. I forgot to censor parts my question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi! How do I solve the new exception? I followed your instructions to add new `component-scan` items in the `dispatcher-servlet`. It always asks for a bean :/

Comment: can you update the question with the new configuration and the packages of each class?

Comment: What if you place the component scan for controllers after the component scan for the service?

Comment: @thekalaban Glad I could help.  Do you understand why that fixed things?

Comment: Yes. I got caught up with assembling the Spring from memory and various tutorials online hence the messy code declarations. Your suggestion to clear the duplication did it (ie `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, `<context:annotation-config>`). Thank you Sir! Have a Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

in your controller add the following

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("calcArffService")
private CalcArffService calcArffService; // causes trouble tbh
```

and it should work. Also add `context:component-scan` to you spring config to allo annotation scanning.

Comment: Thank you! I added the `@Qualifier` but the console now showed `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app.service.CalcArffService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=calcArffService)}`. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: context:component-scan is missing then to scan the base package of your services.

Comment: `@Qualifier` isn't needed, default autowiring is done by type. However if you lack the means of autowiring (`<context:component-scan />`) nothing is available for autowiring and thus it will fail.

Comment: it makes the code more readable and understandable. I prefer to use it.